# d3: drawing multiple rectangles using areas

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to draw draw many filled rectangles inside a graph and would like to achieve this using svg paths. 
(I'm not using the rect tag because perfomance will suffer over time.)

My current approach uses the d3.svg.area to generate the path for each area, but the rectangles are not being drawn properly.

As far as I understand the rendered path attribute, it seems that path is missing a moveTo per rectangle.

The following is my simplified code of the problem.

```
var data = [
    {x0:0,x1:50,y0:0,y1:10},
    {x10:0,x1:60,y0:20,y1:30},
    ];

var width = 500;
var barHeight = 20;

var areaFunc = d3.svg.area()
            //.interpolate('step')            
            .x0(function(d){return d.x0;})
            .x1(function(d){return d.x1;})
            .y0(function(d){return d.y0;})
            .y1(function(d){return d.y1;});

var chart = d3.select('#chart')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', barHeight * data.length);

chart.append('path')
            //.data(data)
            .attr('d', areaFunc(data))
            .attr('class', 'absences area')
            .attr('style', 'fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:1');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kLdkgz8/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zh1vqfos/1/? Have just changed the data

Comment: a bit better :) but I would be expecting two rectangles from my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want several rectangles, you need to define your data like that

```
var data = [
    [{x0:10,x1:60,y0:0,y1:0},{x0:10,x1:60,y0:20,y1:20}], // rect 1
    [{x0:100,x1:600,y0:20,y1:20},{x0:100,x1:600,y0:200,y1:200}]// rect 2
];
```

And call it like that

```
chart.selectAll('path')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', areaFunc)
        .attr('class', 'absences area')
        .attr('style', 'fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:1');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/zh1vqfos/2/

Comment: also worth noting that if your object keys are the default d3 ones (x0, y0 etc) then you don't need to define the accessor functions in the OP